# Spring Boot Default Form Login (/login) causes HTTP ERROR 404 after HTTPS implementation for some reason

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, spring-security, https

After implementing HTTPS in application.properties I can go to the pages specified in my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter anonymously like I want. However, when I go to a page the requires authorization I get a HTTP ERROR 404 page not found:

"This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost/login
HTTP ERROR 404".

If I take away the https implementation in application.properties then I can go to the pages I want anonymously and if I go to anything else there is a nice default login form. Why wont this same behavior occur with https implemented????

**application.properties:**

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server4.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.key-alias=1

security.require-ssl=true
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {



    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/save","/success", "/images/**","/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved this. I had two issues. The first issue is that I needed to specify an antmatcher for /login/**. Also, my server is running on port 80 in application.properties, so everytime I was going to https://.. the browser sent it over 443 and it wouldn't show up unless I specified https://localhost:80/..

WebSecurityAdapter Configuration:

```
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/","/login/**", "/save","/success", "/images/**","/css/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin();

    }
```

```
#default server port
server.port=443

#SSL
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:server4.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=******
server.ssl.key-alias=1

security.require-ssl=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I was able to fix it by changing `server.port=8080` to `server.port=8443` in `application.yaml`.